# Java while loop in threads

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop

I have written a program in Java which has 5 threads. In the run() I have a while loop which will loop over and over and this loop will loop a lot of times.

While the program is running, it is gradually eating ram bringing the program to a crawl. Is there anyway I can stop it eating all my ram?

**Edit:**
Actually just thinking about it, it probably is because the loop is creating lots of objects. Should I = null those objects at the end of the while loop??

Comment: Post the loop in the thread. Are you allocating memory in the for loop? That could be the problem.

Comment: Could we see what your threads are doing?

Comment: To answer your question, it would be interesting what you're doing in the run methods. However I assume that your creating there a lot of new objects, which will exceed your memory sooner or later?

Comment: You're going to have to post here the code in that devilish `while` loop.

Comment: Actually just thinking about it, it probably is because the loop is creating lots of objects. Should I = null those objects at the end of the while loop??

Comment: @DRKM, it depends on what you do with those objects after you create them. Are you holding on to a reference of those objects?

Answer (score 8):

If you are creating new objects and saving them in some collection in your loop that would easily fill up memory very quickly.

What you need to do is make sure you aren't saving any extra objects that you don't need.

Also, you should optimize the logic in your threads to consume the least amount of memory.

Comment: Now THIS is a real answer, even without enough information. (+1)

Comment: I love pithy remarks as much as the next guy, but yes, this is more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

> While the program is running, it is
>   gradually eating ram bringing the
>   program to a crawl. Is there anyway I
>   can stop it eating all my ram?

Sure. Change your code so that it uses less RAM.

Comment: @Justin, I think, Michael is just waiting for the OP to provide a few more details (or code) ;-)

Comment: Why does this have +5? This is a ridiculous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Specific to @Michael Borgwardt's answer, try to minimize the creation of new objects.  If you can re-use the same object instead of creating new ones every time, you can save some memory there.

But as others have said, without seeing your code, we're just guessing.

Comment: What ultimately causes OutOfMemoryErrors is generally *not* the creation of new objects, but keeping references to unneeded old objects.

Comment: @Michael, He didn't say he was getting OOMs, he said it was slowing to a crawl.  That implies to me that he's doing lots of garbage collection.

Comment: Yeah, but current generational garbage collectors can churn through lots of short-lived objects without consuming significant resources. "Slowing to a crawl" typically happens when memory is truely running out and the GC has to work hard constantly to fulfill its "do everything possible to free memory before throwing OOM Errors" until the very end.

Comment: @Michael, like I said in the answer, without code we're just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal for each one of your thread to have an infinite `while` loop, but simply having the while loops does not use up more RAM.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                // do some work
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {}
    }
}).start();
```

You're doing something to consume the RAM, so you must debug your application and find the cause of the increased RAM usage.

### Update:

You don't have to make the objects `null` at the end of the loop... if you're not holding on to a reference of those objects then the garbage collector should clean them up. What are you doing with the objects after you create them? How much RAM are you using up?

Answer (score 1):

You might need a memory analyzer to understand what is "eating RAM". There are many tools available. One commercial tool is [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).

A simple and free tool is to use Sun Profiler supplied with Java VisualVM. If you have JDK 6 installed you probably already have this program installed on your computer. Run the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\jvisualvm.exe. Connect to the running Java process and press the Profiler tab and Memory button. You can now see what objects you have and how much memory they are using. Press refresh to update the view.